# htaccess remove extension from url works but the page doesn't load

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I managed to get /about.php to change to /about with

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
```

But now the page doesn't load. Why?
Any help is much appreciated!

UPDATE:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine On
# Do the .php removal first
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/profile.php?username=$1

# Only do this if the .php exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've gotten as far as to probe the incoming request for `.php` and redirect the browser without the `.php`, but you still need another rule to catch the subsequent URI without `.php` and silently execute it *with* `.php`.

```
RewriteEngine On
# Do the .php removal first
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

# And add a catch-all rule to point requests to .php silently
# if the file exists.
#
# Don't interfere with real file requests:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Only do this if the .php exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Requests like `/something` for which `/something.php` doesn't actually exist will still return a 404, but `/something` where `/something.php` *does* exist will silently execute `/something.php` without changing the browser address bar from `/something`.

Now, the above will remove `.php` even if the file doesn't actually exist, so a request to `/notexist.php` will redirect the user to `/notexist` which will result in a 404. If you don't want to even bother redirecting those to just return 404 on `/notexist.php`, you could do the following to make sure it just returns 404 right away:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
```

#### Update: Order matters.

Seeing other rules already in place, these are highly sensitive to the order they're executed in, particularly since you have a catch-all `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/profile.php?username=$1`

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine On

# This removes /index.php, do this first
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

# Do the .php removal next
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

# /pages is specific, so do it next
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]

# Only do this if the .php exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]

# Then the more generic one to write username
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

I have tested all of these and verified them in my own environment.

Comment: please look at my update. it still doesn't work and the page does exist so it should load

Comment: Order matters! Please always post _all_ your rules when you seek help with mod_rewrite. hang on...

Comment: @Gadgetster Ok, I reordered them in a more logical way

Comment: this still throws me to an error 404 page although I have about.php and other pages.. im on localhost if that makes a difference

Comment: What exact URL are you starting with, and where does `about.php` exist? Your rules imply that it exists at the root `/about.php.   Also, browsers may cache redirects aggressively. Test it with a different browser.

Comment: I am using http://localhost/test/ my index.php and about.php are in the main folder the 'test' folder. I just tried firefox and still the same issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53912/discussion-between-gadgetster-and-michael-berkowski)